# PayPal rest-api-sdk-php with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to find out how to actually use the 'rest-api-sdk-php' with Laravel 4 ... I've updated composer and the library is ready to be used, but do I need to add an alias to the `app.php` file?

I've tried calling `$apiContext = new ApiContext` but `ApiContext` cannot be found.

I just don't see any reference to how to actually use this library at all.

Help initiating a call would be most apprecaited!

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-auto`? This command adds the classes to Composer's autoload mapping.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't make a difference. I just don't know how I'm supposed to initiate the API.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

A Paypal package for Laravel 4 if you need. https://github.com/xroot/laravel-paypalpayment

It internally uses the REST SDK

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the following line as the PayPal classes are under their own namespace.

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
```

Do the same for the rest of the PayPal classes you will be using on your controller

Comment: Yeah, this got me past my first hurdle ... but now I'm dealing with the fact that there is no JSON response whatsoever ... the PayPal API is the WORST!

Comment: Do you have any idea what the Service Provider should be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using ***laravel-paypalpayment***.
It is a simple package that helps you to process direct credit card payments, stored credit card payments and PayPal account payments with your Laravel 4/5 projects using **PayPal REST API SDK**. 
Below is link given:
https://github.com/xroot/laravel-paypalpayment